# Camera activity return make button behaviour lost

Tags: java, android

I'm a total beginner in Android and I tried to make an app that exploit the camera.

In this application a FloatingActionButton is the button that triggered the camera (code below).

This button is **hide** if the bottomsheet is **expand** and **show** if it's **collapse**.

All of it **work** **perfectly** the **first** **time** I use the button.

Indeed, **once** the **picture** is **taken** and the **mainactivity** is **back**, the **button** **doesn't** **work** **anymore** and furthermore is **behavior** is "**lost**" too (which means that the FloatingActionButton is always shown).

I don't understand what is the source of this bug.

You'll find next to this post 2 screen, one before the button is clicked and one after and the code called in my fragment that make the onclick listener of the button :

The button is hidden when the bottomsheet is expanded (before camera was used):
[image: The button is hidden when the bottomsheet is expanded (before camera was used)]

The button is shown, even if the bottomsheet is expanded (after camera was used):
[image: The button is showed, even if the bottomsheet is expanded (after camera was used)]

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapsHandler = new MapsHandler(getActivity());
        mBottomSheetHandler = new BottomSheetHandler(getActivity());

        FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivity(intent); //On change d'activite
            }
        });
```